# USB Boot Failure after using pendrivelinux

Tags: boot, live-usb

I have created a Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop (32-bit) Live USB using the [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) Universal USB Creator. I selected the "Format Drive with FAT32" option, added maximum Persistent Storage, but other than those, I simply created the USB.  When I start my computer and select to boot using USB HDD, my computer gives me the error message, `Warning! Boot Failure.`

The USB seems to be loaded with all the necessary stuff.  I did not manipulate it after creating it.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try install to USB stick using UNetBootin, that is much more easier to create a working bootable USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating live usb from Windows.

Universal USB Creator is indeed a very good tool. I have installed Ubuntu around 200 computers, some computers accept the live usb created using Universal USB installer, some doesn't. I am not sure about what makes the difference. But we have options left.

**From Windows**,
You can go for [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

---

**From any other Ubuntu system**

Option 1:- Use **UNETBOOTIN** (you can find it from Ubuntu Software Center).

Option 2:- Use **Startup-Disk Creator** (Comes default with Ubuntu).